# Aggregate Excel Table and add custom columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables, excel-365

could you give me a hint how to link one table to the other table so that the second table is an aggregated version of the first table (e.g. filtered In Scope) and the second table is followed by additional columns.
The second table should also be actualized in the case, if I insert a new row in the first table and filter it as "in Scope".

**Table1**
[image: Table1]

**Table2**
[image: Table2]

I hope I could explain it to you and thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Mo

I've tried it to connect via PowerQuery but the problem is, if I actualize my query the additional added rows are moving an they dont have match to the right row.

I also created two tables but if i use Vlookup i got #SPILL!

I also tried to connect it via the formula Filter but in this case i get the right rows but cannot sort it.

Comment: According to the documentation, the `SORT` function is not available in `2019`. Can you upgrade? How are you wanting to sort the results? What formulas have you actually tried? What Power Query code have you used?

Comment: If you're receiving a spill error you can't be on Excel 2019, which doesn't spill. You either have Office 365 or Excel 2021. But if you share the formula you used, we may be able to fix it.

Comment: Sorry yes its Office365. I've mistake with Project 2019. Yes Excel is on Office 365.

Comment: Then you can just use the `FILTER` and `SORT` functions. Show the formulas you've actually tried.

Comment: Use proper `Excel Tags` it lets members to know what version you are using, perhaps I have made the relevant changes now.